# Python: Задача на разделение изображения на части

Tags: python, изображения, координаты

Всех приветствую!

Думаю над решением такой задачи:

дано абсолютно произвольное изображение, а также текстовый файл, содержащий в себе координаты точек треугольников в следующем формате:

```
tr_1, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3
```

Координаты вершин треугольников образуют так называемые "особые зоны" вышеупомянутого изображения, т.е. если мы на изображении отметим точки с координатами (x1;y1), (x2;y2) и (x3;y3), то получившийся треугольник будет "особой зоной" изображения, при этом количество "особых зон" ограничено только размерами изображения.

Необходимо разбить изображение таким образом, чтобы не было случаев, когда одна половина "особой зоны" находится в одной части, а оставшаяся часть - в другой. При этом имеется следующее ограничение: максимальные размеры части: 512x512 пикселей.

На выходе мы должны получить следующее:

1. Части исходного изображения, результат разделения. (была, например, одна картинка, а по итогу мы получаем n изображений)
2. Текстовый файл содержащий в себе: исходный номер треугольника, название части изображения, в которой он оказался и координаты x1-x3, y1-y3 для данной части.

```
tr_1 part_1.png, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3
```

При этом резать изображение можно как угодно: хоть прямыми, хоть кривыми.

Есть у кого-нибудь мысли, как поднобное можно решить? Что стоит глянуть для решения?

Comment: вы бы написали, что это за задача - если учебная, то тему, к которой относится.

Comment: увы, задача не учебная, так что конкретную тему подсказать проблематично